# Does Ruby have an equivalent of JAR files in Java | Attempting to reduce the size of a docker image

Tags: ruby, docker

I am working on containerizing a ruby application (not proficient in Ruby). My docker image size after installing all related dependencies was 1.18GB. I was working on implementing multi-stage builds and this is what my Dockerfile looks like right now.

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app
RUN bundle install --full-index

FROM ruby:2.5.1 as runner
EXPOSE 36081
ADD docker/config/env_config.rb /etc/flo
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/ /usr/src/app/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bundle/ /usr/local/bundle/
ENTRYPOINT /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

But I could only reduce it to 917 MB. I am trying to further reduce this size, and was wondering if Ruby had a JAR counterpart that I am unaware of? Basically, how can I reduce the size of copying all Gems from `/usr/local/bundle/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard [Docker Hub `ruby` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) is based on a [`buildpack-deps` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps/), which includes a substantial number of build-time-only dependencies, like C header files.  This base image is ~300 MB on its own, and that carries through to the `ruby` image.  Using a smaller image for the actual runtime image can help:

```sh
FROM ruby:2.5.1 AS builder # use the full image for building gems
...

FROM ruby:2.5.1-slim # but a reduced image for the final application
COPY --from=builder ...
```

Ruby has the concept of a `.gem` file, but it's just a packaged copy of the contents in the `/usr/local/bundle` tree.

The other particularly likely source of space is the `vendor` directory tree used by Bundler.  You can include `vendor` in a `.dockerignore` file to keep it from being sent to `docker build` at all (better); or you can `RUN rm -rf /usr/src/app/vendor` *in the first stage* to remove it if it happens to appear.

In any case, you can further debug what's going on by changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` at the end of the Dockerfile, and then `docker run --rm -it your-image bash`.  That will give you an interactive shell in a new container based on the built image, and you can look around with tools like `du` to find where the space has gone.

Comment: The `.gem` file that you mentioned, is that a packaged file for the entire project? How would I generate that and copy it to the next stage and run it?

Comment: You'd run [`gem build`](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-build).  The gem wouldn't include any library dependencies, only the application code itself (in Java terminology, like a "skinny" jar).  This would be approximately the same size as the unpacked contents, so I don't think it'd really help your size issue.

Comment: I see. I couldn't find the `vendor` directory tree in my image either, so it looks like the only reduction I can get is using the slim image.